# how can pass T dynamicaly in Ilist<T>?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4.1

i have a question.i have a method (Filter),i want to pass T dynamic.but it dosen`t accept.how can i do it?

```
 public List<T> Filter<T>(string TypeOfCompare)
    {


        List<T> ReturnList2 = new List<T>();
         return ReturnList2;
    }
IList MakeListOfType(Type listType)
    {
        Type listType1 = typeof(List<>);
        Type specificListType = listType.MakeGenericType(listType1);

        return (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(specificListType);
    }
 Filter < ConstructGenericList(h) > ("s");
```

Comment: You can't; generics are checked at compile time, that's the whole point.  That's not to say there aren't better ways to accomplish what you need.  Instead of giving us a proposed solution that doesn't make sense, tell us what you are trying to achieve at a high level.

Answer (score 1):

```
IList MakeListOfType(Type listType)
{
    Type listType1 = typeof(List<>);
    Type specificListType = listType.MakeGenericType(listType1);

    return (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(specificListType);
}
```

It should be the other way round, you should call `MakeGenericType` on the generic type definition, not on the generic type argument. So the code becomes this:

```
IList MakeListOfType(Type elementType)
{
    Type listType = typeof(List<>);
    Type specificListType = listType.MakeGenericType(elementType);

    return (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(specificListType);
}
```

(note that I changed the variables names to make the code clearer)

Answer (score 0):

Generic parameters must have a type able to be determined at compile time (without resorting to something like functional type inference that some other languages have).  So, you can't just stick a function between the angle brackets to get the type you want.

**Edit:**

Now that I know what you're trying to do, I would suggest a different approach entirely.

You mention that you are using Entity Framework, and you are trying to use one method to get a list of different types of objects.  Those objects -- like Student and Teacher -- must have something in common, though, else you would not be trying to use the same method to retrieve a list of them.  For example, you may just be wanting to display a name and have an ID to use as a key.

In that case, I would suggest defining an interface that has the properties common to Student, Teacher, etc. that you actually need, then returning a list of that interface type.  Within the method, you would essentially be using a variant of the factory pattern.

So, you could define an interface like:

```
public interface INamedPerson
{
    int ID { get; }
    string FirstName { get; }
    string LastName { get; }
}
```

Make your entities implement this interface.  Auto-generated entities are (typically) partial classes, so in your own, new code files (*not* in the auto-generated code files themselves), you would do something like:

```
public partial class Student : INamedPerson
{
    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return StudentId;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public partial class Teacher : INamedPerson
{
    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return TeacherId;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you may not even need to add the `ID` property if you already have it.  However, if the identity property in each class is different, this adapter can be one way to implement the interface you need.

Then, for the method itself, an example would be:

```
public List<INamedPerson> MakeListOfType(Type type)
{
    if (type == typeof(Student))
    {
        // Get your list of students.  I'll just use a made-up
        // method that returns List<Student>.
        return GetStudentList().Select<Student, INamedPerson>(s => (INamedPerson)s)
                               .ToList<INamedPerson>();
    }
    if (type == typeof(Teacher))
    {
        return GetTeacherList().Select<Teacher, INamedPerson>(t => (INamedPerson)t)
                               .ToList<INamedPerson>();
    }
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid type.");
}
```

Now, there are certainly ways to refine this pattern.  If you have a lot of related classes, you may want to use some sort of dependency injection framework.  Also, you may notice that there is a lot of duplication of code.  You could instead pass a function (like `GetStudentList` or `GetTeacherList`) by doing something like

```
public List<INamedPerson> GetListFromFunction<T>(Func<IEnumerable<T>> theFunction) where T : INamedPerson
{
    return theFunction().Select<T, INamedPerson>(t => (INamedPerson)t).ToList<INamedPerson>();
}
```

Of course, using this function requires, once again, the type passed in to be known at compile time.  However, at some point, you're going to have to decide on a type, so maybe that is the appropriate time.  Further, you can make your life a little simpler by leaving off the generic type at method call time; as long as you are passing in a function that takes no arguments and returns an `IEnumerable` of objects of the same type that implement `INamedPerson`, the compiler can figure out what to use for the generic type `T`.

Comment: i have a checkbox that item are Student,teacher,..that they are my entity.i want to when user select one of them i get (for example user select student)name and via MakeListOfType method i make a list of student,i want to pass list to my filter method and do somethings.how can i do that?